# Set Partition , approximation, optimal solution --need help in designing algorithm and writing its psedocode in latex

Tags: approximation, set-partition

Let S = {S1, . . . , Sn} be a set of sets of integers, e.g. S = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}}.
We say that D = {D1, . . . , Dk} is a partition of S if the following conditions
hold.
• Di ⊆ S for every i ∈ {1, . . . , k}
• All sets in D are pairwise disjoint.
• D1 ∪ D2 ∪ · · · ∪ Dk = S
The problem consists in finding a partition D of S such that:
• The cardinality of D is a minimum
• For every Di ∈ D it holds that ∩S∈DiS != ∅.
Your task is
need your help to Design an algorithm that gives a solution or an approximated solution and also pseudocode description of the algorithm in latex. explain the rationality behind your algorithm.

Comment: If I interpret the problem correctly, this is the "[exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover)" problem, with Knuth's [Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) offered in the Wikipedia page as a good solution.

Comment: Thanks John. Can you let me know how to proceed for set problem? the expected solution is { { {1,3}, {3,4} } ,  { {2,4} {2,5} } }